# Error: Entity is not api accessible at line 1 column 1

Tags: trigger, tab, record

```
trigger Stage on Opportunity (After insert, After update) {

    for (opportunity opp : trigger.new) {
        if (opp.StageName = 'Closed won') {
            for ( product pro: trigger.new) {
                pro.Available_for_lease__c = FALSE;
            }


        }
    }


}
```

I'm new to apex and i need to update the value of a checkbox in the object "room" if the stage is set to closed won which is in the opportunity object.

Comment: Which Field on what object do you need to update?

Comment: i need to update the value of the checkbox "available_for_lease__c in products object with the use of opportunity stage picklist value"close won

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the Product object which isn't available - Product2 is the type you need.

There is a problem with trying to access the Product(2) items by using the trigger.new collection - it will be a collection of Opportunities not Products...

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
trigger UpdateLease on Opportunity (after update) {
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity op : trigger.new){
        if(op.StageName.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed Won')){
            oppIds.add(op.Id);
        }
    }
    if(!oppIds.isEmpty()){
        List<Product2> products = [Select yourField from Product2 where OpportunityId /*Lookup Field*/ in : oppIds];
        for(Product2 prod : products){
            prod.yourfield=true;
        }
        update products;
    }

}
```

The above trigger is in crude state. Please refine it.
I suggest you read Apex Workbook to get idea about the triggers.

> [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/)

Comment: What if `op.StageName` is `null`? The `==` ignores case fyi and is null-safe.